# Error when trying to install any package from NuGet

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

I'm getting a message like this when trying to install a package using NuGet:

`Install-Package : Unable to find package 'Newtonsoft.Json'.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  Newtonsoft.Json
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand`

(the same error for other packages). Tried to reinstall NuGet - no success.
Any other ideas?

Comment: Is the correct package source selected in the Package Manager Console?

Comment: @Matt Ward, it was incorrect (I had "Microsoft and .NET" selected instead); after changing it to nuget.org I'm getting this error: "The source at nuget.org [https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/] is unreachable. Falling back to NuGet Local Cache"

Comment: The source at nuget.org is unreachable is normally a temporary networking problem. Sometimes you can fix it by restarting Visual Studio.